# MapBox crashes on the latest Flutter version

Tags: flutter, mapbox, flutter-dependencies, mapbox-gl

MapBox map isn't working on the latest Flutter version (`Flutter 3.3.2`, `Dart 2.18.1`), but it works for my colleague but he is using `v3.3.1.` and Dart `v2.18.0`

How can I downgrade to that version?

When I do `flutter downgrade v.3.3.1` in the terminal, it wants to downgrade to the previous version that was used, and for me, that was `v2.8.1`, and I can't seem to upgrade to a specific version, tried switching channels, but it didn't help.

And the problem is definitely in Flutter version.

**Any ideas on how to upgrade(or downgrade) to a specific version?**

**Or maybe you have an idea why MapBox is crashing?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can Google for answers on how to downgrade your Flutter version. Or ask about the Mapbox issue on stackoverflow or create an issue in their repo. Do not combine different questions.

Answer (score 1):

use [FVM](https://medium.com/embrace-it/a-brief-introduction-to-flutter-version-management-ff240dafdbf6)  it will help to choose different flutter versions for different projects, so you can test different flutter versions